# error in removing everything else from pandas dataframe using re.sub()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df which as some of the variables that has alphanumeric text in it.

```
data = {
 col1: ['xyz Res  ' '   Navigation' 'After   Hours' 'Internal review @!'],
 col2: ['Help?Desk' 'Supplier @ 123  &%' 'Unprofiled Manager  ?  ' 'Air ? Online']
}
```

I want to have a DF without white space, special character such as @!&%? etc.

I am trying to remove everything else except alphanumeric in padas dataframe using the following code:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.re.sub('[^a-zA-Z\d\s]', '', x) if x.dtype == "object" else x)
```

it is throwing error:

```
 AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 're'", 'occurred at index col1')
```

Any help on it please?

Comment: Can you make an reproducible example? Also, what error is thrown?

Comment: `x` is a `series`. There is no `re.sub` method for `series`. What you need is [`series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) which is equivalent to `re.sub`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.replace` instead:

```
data = {"col1": ['xyz Res  ' '   Navigation' 'After   Hours' 'Internal review @!',
          'Help?Desk' 'Supplier @ 123  &%' 'Unprofiled Manager  ?  ' 'Air ? Online'],}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["col1"] = df["col1"].str.replace('[^a-zA-Z\d\s]', '')

print (df)

                                                col1
0  xyz Res     NavigationAfter   HoursInternal re...
1  HelpDeskSupplier  123  Unprofiled Manager    A...
```

Comment: Thanks. this is really useful.